# Passing header values

Tags: php

Hi having a problem forming my syntax this is what iv'e got.

```
    $id = $_POST['student_id'];
    $getlev= $_POST['lev'];
    header('Location: usucess.php?id='.$id.'&getlev='.$getlev);
```

and this is the receiving end.

```
     if(empty($_POST['lvl'])){
              $yl= $_GET['getlev'];
         }else{
              $yl=$_POST['lvl'];}
```

Currently it is only passing **$id** would appreciate any help on what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: There is a difference between `$_POST` and `$_GET`. Please make yourself comfortable with the programming language first. Mistakes can happen, but not each mistake one does is worth to post a question here, especially as you'll get many answers from other users "just guessing" which then is not of much help. Instead learn how to debug your issue, that will bring you much more steps forward. `var_dump` is your friend.

Comment: Yes i want to check if lvl is empty if it is i want **$yl** to get its value from **getlev** **NOTE**: lev and lvl are different.

Comment: Then please read about request variables in PHP first: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php - Also properly indent your code when you post a question, other users here need to read it.

Comment: @hakre I'm sorry for wasting your time and others i was expecting a little patience and help from experts guess not instead I'm given a manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem I think is mismatch:

`lvl` vs `lev`

Comment: Nope lvl and lev are different.

Comment: What provides the `lvl` POST value to be sent along the redirect?

Comment: example. I'm on page show it passes **lvl** to page update, I now then put **lvl** to **$getlev** and returns it to page show.

Comment: Ok, but what code passes the `lvl` variable to `usucess.php` (I assume the "receiver side" is the usucess.php, and the header you send out is a redirect to that, with the two GET parameters passed.) I can't see, how that parameter makes it to the other PHP script...

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out i think i now whats the problem! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it would only pass ID because on the receiving end you have a new condition

```
if (empty($_POST['lvl'])) {
    $yl = $_GET['getlev'];
}
```

`$yl = $_GET['getlev'];` would never be set if `$_POST['lvl']` is empty

Comment: On the passing page $_POST'lvl'] is not empty because it is performing a function.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to escape your variables when sending them as parameters to the query string.
I personally prefer [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) so you'd write your code like so:
`header('Location: usucess.php?id='.urlencode($id).'&getlev='.urlencode($getlev));`

And the answer you are looking for I think is that your `if` statement is backwards.
Try:

```
if(!empty($_POST['lvl'])){
          $yl= $_GET['getlev'];
}else{
          $yl=$_POST['lvl'];
}
```